# How to scraping "hidden" table in HTML code with R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I need to scraping all tables (summary, defensive, offensive and pasing) that appears in this web:

https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/52/Archive/Spain-Real-Madrid

When I check the html code inspecting with the tool for developers of Chrome I can see the data but if I see the source code as plain text in other tab of Chrome the data are not.
I try with the next code:

```
con <- url("https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/52/Archive/Spain-Real-Madrid")
htmlCode <- readLines(con)
close(con)
htmlCode[grepl("Ronaldo",htmlCode)]
```

Obviously not find the data that I need. What can I do?

Comment: library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.whoscored.com/Teams/52/Archive/Spain-Real-Madrid")
Sys.sleep(40)
doc<-htmlTreeParse(remDr$getPageSource(),asText=TRUE)
topxml <- xmlSApply(topxml,function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))

# Data Cleaning required after this.

Comment: Didn't really use dev tools as in-depth as you should have https://www.whoscored.com/StatisticsFeed/1/GetPlayerStatistics?category=summary&subcategory=all&statsAccumulationType=0&isCurrent=false&playerId=&teamIds=52&matchId=&stageId=11810&tournamentOptions=&sortBy=Rating&sortAscending=&age=&ageComparisonType=&appearances=&appearancesComparisonType=&field=Overall&nationality=&positionOptions=&timeOfTheGameEnd=&timeOfTheGameStart=&isMinApp=false&page=&includeZeroValues=true&numberOfPlayersToPick=

Comment: @Bharath I try use your code but I obtain the next error:
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
   class: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: @hrbrmstr That is the reason because I question